# Qtip content prerender gives JavaScript runtime error:

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I am using qtip1.0. I need to show the qtip in a function call.

If I use content prerender: true, it gives the below mentioned error.

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'nodeName' of
>   undefined or null reference

I have added this in my master page.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have the following code in MY page document ready function.

```
 $('#printDiv').qtip(
       {

           show: {
               event: 'click', // Show it on click
               solo: true // And hide all other tooltips
           },

           content: {
               prerender: true,
               title: {
                   text: 'Core Details',
                   button: 'Close'
               },
               text: 'Show the content'

           },

           position: {
               target: $(this).closest($(document.body)), // Position it via the document body...
               corner: 'center' // ...at the center of the viewport
           },

           style: {
               width: { max: 650 },
               padding: '14px',
               border: {
                   width: 9,
                   radius: 9,
                   color: '#666666'
               },
               name: 'light'
           },
           api: {
               beforeShow: function () {
                   // Fade in the modal "blanket" using the defined show speed
                   $('#qtip-blanket').fadeIn(this.options.show.effect.length);
               },
               beforeHide: function () {
                   // Fade out the modal "blanket" using the defined hide speed
                   $('#qtip-blanket').fadeOut(this.options.hide.effect.length);
               }
           }
       });



        // Create the modal backdrop on document load so all modal tooltips can use it
        $('<div id="qtip-blanket">')
          .css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: $(document).scrollTop(), // Use document scrollTop so it's on-screen even if the window is scrolled
              left: 0,
              height: $(document).height(), // Span the full document height...
              width: '100%', // ...and full width

              opacity: 0.7, // Make it slightly transparent
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              zIndex: 5000  // Make sure the zIndex is below 6000 to keep it below tooltips!
          })
          .appendTo(document.body) // Append to the document body
          .hide(); // Hide it initially
```

Comment: You would do well to post some HTML.

Comment: Don't tag your question with [tag:qtip2] if you're only using version 1... and this brings up another good point... qTip v1 was obsolete more than two years ago when qTip 2 came out... it's time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You never stated which version of jQuery you're trying to use with qTip 1.0.  However, given the fact that qTip 1.0 was rendered obsolete by [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/) more than two years ago, it's safe to say that qTip 1.0 is not compatible with whatever version of jQuery you're using... unless it's really old.

**Solution**:  [Upgrade to qTip2](http://qtip2.com/) (recommended) or [downgrade jQuery to whatever version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery/) was last compatible with qTip 1.0 (not recommended).